# Enable Synchronous IO in Azure Function

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, graphql-dotnet

I am building a HTTPTriggered Azure Function, targeting netcoreapp3.0, that is running a GraphQL .NET server. GraphQL .NET requires that `AllowSynchronousIO` is set to `true`, but I can't figure out how to do that for a Azure Function. I have tried implementing my own `Startup` class that extends `FunctionsStartup` and added the below code in the `Configure` method with no luck.

```
builder.Services
    .AddOptions<KestrelServerOptions>()
    .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
    {
        settings.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        configuration.Bind(settings);
    });
```

The error message I get is:

> An unhandled host error has occurred.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core: Synchronous operations are
>   disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Setting the environment variable `FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE` to `true` seems to solve the issue, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/pull/5286.

Answer (score 3):

**Why error:**

Synchronous IO not enabled

**How to fix:**

Edit the "***local.settings.json***" file in your project root folder
to look like this. ***"FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE": "true"***

```
   {
      "IsEncrypted": false,
      "Values": {
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        //Enable Synchronous IO
        "FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE": "true"
      },
      "Host": {
        "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
        "CORS": "*",
        "CORSCredentials": false
      }
    }
```