Azure Function .Net Code Issue for HttpRequest and BlobServiceClient Assembly or namespace
I have the below code of azure function to read excel file from Azure blob storage but it is giving below 2 errors. I am using .Net framework 4.8 and I also have System.net.http package added to my solution and now i am not sure how to fix the below two issue due to lack of expertise in .Net programming.
I think the issue is because either both the HttpRequest and BlobServiceClient doesn't support .Net 4.8 framework.
Could anyone please help me fix this issue?
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using OfficeOpenXml; // Install the NuGet package "EPPlus"

public static class ExtractEmailsFromExcel
{
    private static readonly string _storageConnectionString = "connectionstring";
    private static readonly string _blobContainerName = "";
    private static readonly string _excelFileName = "";

    [FunctionName("ExtractEmails")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        try
        {
            // Download Excel file from Azure Blob Storage
            var emailAddresses = await DownloadAndExtractEmails(_storageConnectionString, _blobContainerName, _excelFileName);

            // Return list of email addresses
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, emailAddresses);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<List<string>> DownloadAndExtractEmails(string storageConnectionString, string containerName, string fileName)
    {
        var emails = new List<string>();

        using (var client = new BlobServiceClient(storageConnectionString))
        {
            var containerClient = client.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

            if (await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
            {
                var downloadStream = await blobClient.DownloadStreamingAsync();
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await downloadStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;

                    using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(memoryStream))
                    {
                        var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First(); // Assuming first worksheet
                        var emailColumn = 1; // Assuming email addresses are in the first column (index 1)

                        for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++) // Skip header row (index 1)
                        {
                            var email = worksheet.Cells[row, emailColumn].Value?.ToString()?.Trim();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                            {
                                emails.Add(email);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return emails;
    }
}

Errors -

The type or namespace name 'HttpRequest' could not be found (are you
missing a using directive or an assembly
reference?)   ExcelRead   C:\Users\suraj.pardeshi\source\repos\ExcelRead\ExcelRead\Function1.cs   Line
22
The type or namespace name 'BlobServiceClient' could not be found (are
you missing a using directive or an assembly
reference?)   ExcelRead   C:\Users\suraj.pardeshi\source\repos\ExcelRead\ExcelRead\Function1.cs   Line
46

Update - Post running the below code, i don't get any error during compilation however in console and on browser i get below errors due to which i don't get desired output.



You should add the namespace using Azure.Storage.Blobs

Tried adding but didn't worked. Same error.

Use HttpRequestMessage instead of HttpRequest and also install Azure.Storage.Blobs to remove BlobServiceClient error.

Hey Pravallika KV, thanks for you suggestion HttpRequest error is now resolved after replacing it with HttpRequestMessage, however BlobServiceClient error is still there and I already had Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.20.0 nuget package installed in my Dependencies. Any other suggestion could you give to fix it?

Did you add using Azure.Storage.Blobs in function?

Yes, i added that as well at the top of my .cs file but after that it started giving another error along with the existing BlobServiceClient error. Therefore i removed it.

What is the other error you are getting? Is it about CopyToAsync()?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have done few modifications to your code and able to read excel file from Azure Blob Storage.
Code Snippet:
//using ..

using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.Text;

 public static class Function1
 {
     private static readonly string _storageConnectionString = "<Storage_connection_string>";
     private static readonly string _blobContainerName = "containerName";
     private static readonly string _excelFileName = "excelname.xlsx";

     [FunctionName("ExtractEmails")]
     public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
         [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
         ILogger log)
     {
         log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

         try
         {
             ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

             // Download Excel file from Azure Blob Storage
             var emailAddresses = await DownloadAndExtractEmails(_storageConnectionString, _blobContainerName, _excelFileName);

             // Return list of email addresses
             foreach (var email in emailAddresses)
             {
                 log.LogInformation($"Processing email: {email}");

                 // Process each email address as needed
             }
             return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Email addresses in excel processed successfully");
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             log.LogError($"Error: {ex.Message}");
             return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
         }
     }

     private static async Task<List<string>> DownloadAndExtractEmails(string storageConnectionString, string containerName, string fileName)
     {
         var emails = new List<string>();

         Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

         var client = new BlobServiceClient(storageConnectionString);
         var containerClient = client.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
         var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

         if (await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
         {
             var downloadStream = await blobClient.DownloadStreamingAsync();
             using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
             {
                 await downloadStream.Value.Content.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                 memoryStream.Position = 0;

                 using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(memoryStream))
                 {
                     var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First(); // Assuming first worksheet
                     var emailColumn = 1; // Assuming email addresses are in the first column (index 1)

                     for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++) // Skip header row (index 1)
                     {
                         var email = worksheet.Cells[row, emailColumn].Value?.ToString()?.Trim();
                         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                         {
                             emails.Add(email);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return emails;
     }

.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="EPPlus" Version="7.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.39" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="4.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<Storage_connection_string>",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "<Storage_connection_string>",
    "AzureStorage": "<Storage_connection_string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}


Uploaded an Excel(.xslx) file(contains 4 Email Addresses as data) in the Azure Blob Storage Container.


Able to read the Excel contents:
Console Output:


Hey Pravallika KV, thanks for above code. I updated my code and packages accordingly and also upload excel file email id's but when i run the code, i see a console with the same URL but it doesn't display anything below. Post that I tried copying the URL to browser and it says This page isn't working right now and also after i get errors in the console. Added screenshot above for reference.

Are you working .NET framework 4.8? Try adding the app setting "FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE":true in local.settings.json.

Hi Pravallika KV, yes i am using .Net Framework 4.8 and I also tried the above suggestion by referring the "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379971/enable-synchronous-io-in-azure-function"  but still the issue was there. I also checked in csproj we have kept AzureFunction Version as V4 so updated the app set accordingly but still could not fix it.

I have updated the answer with complete .csproj code. Try to use the same code and check.

@SRP, Is it working?

no its still giving the same error.

Create a new project, use my code to read a sample excel file with mail address.
